# How can I view only questions that have a SET of tags?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, tag-search

On Stack Overflow, you can see a list of questions for a tag by clicking on that tag, but how can you list questions that have a particular combination of tags?

Comment: Relevant over on the Meta.SE FAQ: [How do I search for questions with (or without) specific tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5229/194720)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the search field, wrap tags with `[tag1] [tag2]`, like

```
[python] [django]
```

Will result in this [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+django) with the appending tags where you get the idea how it works

```
~.com/questions/tagged/python+django
```